# How to put different priors using rstanarm

Tags: r, stan, rstan, rstanarm

Lets say i have model of a form `y=a_{i} + b_{i,1}*x_{1} + b_{2}*x_{2}`, where `i=1,2,...,12` and i would like to estimate this model using `rstanarm`.

Is it possible to set different priors for each intercept `a_{i}` (so lets say the first 4 have `normal(location = 0, scale = 1, autoscale = TRUE)`, the next 4 have `normal(location = 1, scale = 2, autoscale = TRUE)`, and the last 4 `student_t(df = 1, location = 0, scale = NULL, autoscale = TRUE)`). I would also like to set the same priors for the `b_{i,1}` and lastly `b_{2}~normal(location = 3, scale = 1, autoscale = TRUE)`.

Is it possible to do that with rstanarm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is at most one intercept in the models supported by **rstanarm**, but you can suppress the intercept by including a -1 in the formula and treating the coefficients on the dummy variables as coefficients. For coefficients, you can do something like

`prior = student_t(df = c(rep(Inf, 8), rep(1, 4)),
                  location = c(rep(0, 4), rep(1, 4), rep(0, 4)),
                  scale = c(rep(1, 4), rep(2, 4), rep(1, 4)),
                  autoscale = TRUE)`

But it seems that you are intending some sort of a hierarchical model, in which case the prior for the deviations from the global parameters can only be multivariate normal. See `?prior_decov`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ben. **1)** If I understanding it correctly, by adding the "-1" will also not cause multicollinearity, right ? It is just that the interpretation changes. **2)** What i meant to say with my example, is if you can instead of a vector with the location and the scale paramaters, you can also pass a vector with different distributions ( please correct me if i am wrong, but in your answer you transform the t distrubution to normal by manipulating the df)

Comment: Yes having `-1` or `+0` in a R formula removes the intercept and thus it can include one more level of a factor as a dummy variable.

Comment: No, in the **rstanarm** package, you cannot pass a list or character vector of functions to the `prior` argument. You can only pass vectors for `location`, `scale`, `df`, etc. to one function such as `student_t`. However, since the `student_t` is equivalent to `normal` when the degrees of freedom are infinite, that amounts to using "different" functions in the example you gave originally. With the `brm` function in the **brms** R package, you can specify different prior families for different parameters in the model estimated by Stan.

Comment: In **rstanarm**, you can't. But if you are going to use a Beta prior with binomial data, then you can just compute the posterior distribution analytically.

Comment: Hi Ben, I ask something briefly here and if you could answer it, I will ask it formally on SO.    I have a pre-post-control design. That is, a control group (c) is pretested (pre.c) and post-tested (pos.c). Similarly, a treatment group (t) is prettested (pre.t) and post-tested (pos.t). So we have two groups (*group factor*) tested at two time points (*time factor*).


***Question:***

I was wondering using `rstanarm` we can fit a multilevel regression with both factors (i.e., *time* and *group*) and their *interaction* can be estimated?

Comment: Yes, it is the same syntax as in the **lme4** package; something like `(1 | time \ group)`.